# What is the most secure way to protect a custom CMS from infiltration?

Tags: encryption, passwords, cryptography, network, hash

I have a custom CMS with a randomly generated ASCII 100-character string from [this](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/random-string-generator/) site for both my username/password. I also have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711890/how-to-implement-sha-512-md5-and-salt-encryption-all-for-one-password) following sha512 encryption system, which was created by Sammitch.

Is my CMS prone to infiltration, and if so what practises, code and methods can I use to make the most secure CMS login system?

Also, where should I be storing my CMS? Should it be on a subdomain or another seperate domain to my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also have this following sha512 encryption system, which was created by Sammitch

Why not **use `password_hash`**? The only reason I can think of is that you are using an old version of PHP, in which case you should update PHP.

> I have a custom CMS with a randomly generated ASCII 100-character string from this site for both my username/password.

**Don't use a website to generate passwords.** You can't really check how they generate their strings, and more importantly, you can't really be sure that they don't store all their generated strings on their server (when generating a string, it's definitely send to their server via ajax, so it's not only server-side javascript).

Also, you don't need a 100 char username. If you want more security, just make your password longer. Usernames can be private, but they really aren't required to be, that's what passwords are for.

> Is my CMS prone to infiltration, and if so what practises, code and methods can I use to make the most secure CMS login system?

That's really not a question we can answer here, as it's way too broad and we don't nearly have enough information. For a started on possible vulnerabilities in your CMS, check out the [owasp top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10).

Comment: Wouldn't having both a secure username and password mean 2x protection? I could make my username 'admin', but that's just an easy bypass

Comment: Also is password_hash more secure than crypt?

Comment: @mightyspaj. Maybe, maybe not. The point is that `crypt()` is difficult to use properly. Your custom function may or may not be using it correctly. `password_hash()` has been studied by some very fine minds, and is very simple to use. So use it.